# How can I pass image file from Laravel to Express using Graphql?

Tags: laravel, express, graphql

I have a laravel project and my goal is to pass an image file from laravel to my express project, so that my graphql can save the name of my image file after 
successfully renaming the image and uploading it in my express project.

At the moment, I am using `\Softonic\GraphQL` to query data from my express project. Example:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $client = \Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder::build('http://localhost:3002/graphql');

    $query = '
    query GetUsers($sort:[[String!]!]!){
          users(perPage:10, page: 1, sort: $sort){
            users{
              email
            }
          }
        }
    ';

    $var = [
        'sort' => "email"
    ];
    $response = $client->query($query, $var);
    return $response->getData();
}
```

How should i implement it when uploading an image ? my current code looks like this ..

```
public function updateImg(Request $request)
{
    $client = \Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder::build('http://localhost:3002/graphql');

    $query = '
    mutation updateImage(id:ID!, $image: Upload!){
          updateImage(id:1, image: $image){
            users{
              email
            }
          }
        }
    ';

    $var = [
        'image' => $request->file('uploadImg');
    ];
    $response = $client->query($query, $var);
    return $response->getData();
}
```

On my express, when i inspect my `image` in `console.log()`, it returns empty. 
I am not sure if the way im doing is correct or if it is even achievable.

Comment: Provide some code that you're trying and what issues/errors you faced. Dont expect someone to write code for you from scratch.

Comment: @N69S editing it. accidentally posted it.

Comment: @N69S I've edited my question, mind helping me out ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to add support for uploading files to GraphQL is to add multipart form request support through this [specification](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) by [Jayden Seric](https://medium.com/@jaydenseric). He also provides an [implementation project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload) for certain environments. However, I have only tried and tested this with apollo-client and apollo-server-express.

Comment: I have edited my post, mind taking a look ? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I assume `Upload` is a scalar that you have defined in your schema? I think the problem is that GraphQL doesn't know how to handle this without specific implementation (such as that I mentioned before). The only supported scalar types out of the box are `Int`, `Float`, `String`, `Boolean` and `ID` - [Scalar Types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types)

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that i'm using Apollo and it comes with Upload by default. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/

Comment: On the server also make sure you are using `image.createReadStream` i.e. `const {createReadStream, filename, mimetype} = await <Upload>image;` and 
`const stream = await createReadStream();` to get create the file stream.

Comment: On the link you posted it does actually makes reference this post https://blog.apollographql.com/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675 which refers to Jayden Seric's method on how to send file(s) in the same request as your mutation using the `Upload` scalar.
See the section on **Client Setup**. Actually, the alternative seems to be passing the file as base64-encoded string, but I would imagine then you wouldn't need the `Upload` scalar at all.

Comment: I tried but I'm still receiving empty obj on my server side. yeah true, if Im going to use base64, then the upload scalar wouldn't be needed haha. Anyway, for now, what i did was, I created a route to upload the images with the help of guzzle and return me the path of the file, and after retrieving the path, i save the path using  graphql. Thanks btw for highlighting a few things here and there @gary.